Does an Amulet of Health increase your HP while using Wild Shape?
An Amulet of Health sets your Constitution score to 19 while you are wearing it, and druids can use it while Wild Shaped, as established in this question. However, this question states that an artificer's homunculus servant doesn't gain additional hit points from wearing an Amulet of Health. Monster hit points clearly include their Constitution modifier in the HP calculation, however. Does this mean that a higher Constitution modifier would impact HP while in Wild Shape?

I’ve closed this as a duplicate since it’s been asked before. I’m personally not particularly impressed by the answers on the linked duplicate, so if you aren’t either, let me know and I will bounty the question for a better answer. But this is asking the same thing, so it should be closed.
